# How to redirect to a local HTML file from a Java servlet running on Apache Tomcat server?

Tags: java, html, apache, tomcat, servlets

I created a simple Java servlet which takes login credentials from a HTML form. I check for the username and password, and then redirect to local HTML pages accordingly. I get a "404 : resource not found" error with the command response.sendRedirect. I do know where the error is. I'm not sure how the relative URL is to be. I have placed both the HTML files in the path provided in the argument of sendRedirect.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{   
     String username = request.getParameter("username");
     String password = request.getParameter("password");

     System.out.println(username);
     System.out.println(password);

     if((username.equals("xxx"))&&(password.equals("yyy")))
     {
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/MyServer/WebContent/correct.html");
     }
     else
     {
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/MyServer/MyServer/WebContent/wrong.html");      }
}
```

Comment: First test that the URLs used in your sendRedirect method are working properly. Copy/paste these URLs directly on your browser.
BTW, wrong.html an correct.html have different path.